# form.submit() not including sending submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a code in jQuery which first validate the form using ajax and then resubmit the same form to another location but while resubmitting the submit button value not sending..
What will be the issue??

here's the js code:

```
$.ajax({
    'type': 'post',
    'url': '/inc/do.php',
    'data': $form.serialize(),
    beforeSend: function(){
        $form.find(':input').attr('disabled', true);
        $form.find('.btn').addClass('bdsbld');
        $form.find('.blkr').css('display', 'block');
    },
    error: function(){
        Recaptcha.reload();
        $form.find(':input').attr('disabled', false);
        $form.find('.btn').removeClass('bdsbld');
        $form.find('.blkr').css('display', 'none');
    },
    success: function(d){
        $form.find(':input').removeAttr('disabled');
        if(res=isJSON(d)){
            if(!res.err && res.msg.toLowerCase()==='ok'){
                if(($PRI_KEY=$form.find('input#PRIVATE_KEY')).length) $PRI_KEY.val(res.PRIVATE_KEY);
                $form.append('<input type="hidden" id="PRIVATE_KEY" name="PRIVATE_KEY" value="'+res.PRIVATE_KEY+'" />');
                $form.find('input#do').val('BOOK_AD');
                $form.find('#reCaptchaO').remove();
                form.submit();
            }
            else{
                alert(res.msg);
                Recaptcha.reload();
                $form.find('.btn').removeClass('bdsbld');
                $('#'+res.fld).delay(250).focus();
            }
        }
        else
        if(d!==''){
            alert(d);
            Recaptcha.reload();
            $form.find('.btn').addClass('bdsbld');
        }
        $form.find('.blkr').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

in this code, the line i.e.

```
form.submit();
```

is re-submitting the form but it is not including the submit button and its value but the submit button was included in the ajax request... why??

Comment: any workaround for this??
I want the form to be resubmitted with all fields & buttons..

Comment: it seems entirely unnecessary for you to require a static value field contained in a submit button.  See my answer for possible alternative.

Comment: hmmm... its seems you are correct to add dynamic value...
thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the submit button is only included in the form submission traditionally when said submit button is clicked.

since you're not submitting the form via the traditional `input="submit"` button, no value is included.

If you're checking for this value on the server-side, it's a static value that could be easily accomplished with a static hidden input, doesn't seem to be a reason to *fake* a clicked submit button to retrieve a static value.

```
<input type="hidden" value="info" name="field_name" id="field_name" />
```

Answer (score 7):

Submit buttons are only considered [successful](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) controls if they are used to submit the form. Since you are submitting the form using JavaScript, you aren't using the submit button, so it isn't successful, and it isn't included in submitted request.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method 
before form.submit(). call the submit button with click function. so, it traditionally calls the submit button.

document.form name.submit button name.click();

Comment: This works as well: 'document.getElementById('submitButton').click();'